# Calculate an integral using Riemann sum

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-sum

Using the Upper and lower Riemann sum, calculate : $\int^3_1$ $x$

Upper sum : 
$\sum\limits^n _{i=1} =supremum_k * (x_{k-1} , x_k)$

Lower sum: $\sum\limits^n _{i=1}=infimum_k * (x_{k-1} , x_k)$

I have tried using a  equipartition $(1+2k)\over n$ and $3k\over n$but I couldn't arrive to the final result which is 4

Comment: The answer is 4.

Comment: I have just realised that I have calculated the area of a triangle instead of a rhombus. Consequences of a Lot of hours studying Calculus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you divide $[1,3]$ into $n$ identical intervals: $1,1+\frac2n,1+\frac4n,\ldots,1+\frac{2n}n=3$. Then the upper sum will be$$\frac2n\sum_{k=1}^n\left(1+\frac{2k}n\right)=2+2\frac{n+1}n$$and $\inf_{n\in\mathbb N}2+2\frac{n+1}n=4$. Can you do the same with the lower sum?

Comment: I can't figure it out how you arrived to the result of the upper sum

Comment: @user547600 At each interval $\left[1+\frac{2(k-1)}n,1+\frac{2k}n\right]$, $\sup x=1+\frac{2k}n$. And the length of the interval is $\frac2n$.